# for $0<\alpha,\beta<2$, prove that $\int_0^4f(t)dt=2[\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)]$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I got the answer for the question but I have made an assumption, but I don,t know if it's correct.

***Attempt:***

Let $g(x)=\int_0^{x^2}f(t)dt$ and let $h(x)=g'(x)=2xf(x^2)$

now, applying intermediate value theorem for $h(x)$ in $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$, there exists a point $x=k$ such that,
$$h(k)=\frac{h(\alpha)+h(\beta)}{2}=\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)$$
$$g'(k)=\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)$$
***assumption: Now, for g(x), if $x=k$ also satisfies Mean value theorem and since $0<k<2$,***

$$g'(k)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{4}f(t)dt=\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)$$

Hence, $$\int_0^{4}f(t)dt=2[\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)]$$

Comment: Doesn't seam to be correct. Just consider $f$ defined: $f(x) = 0$ for $0 <= x <= 2$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $2 < x <= 4$. Then $\int_0^{4}f(t)dt > 0$ and $2[\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)] = 0$.

Comment: Can't I solve the problem using Mean Value Theorem and Intermediate value theorem instead considering some function? I like to go by the basics.

Comment: There is nothing to prove here

Comment: If the value of $\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)$ doesn't depend on choice of $\alpha$ or $\beta$, then $xf(x)$ must be a constant function $C$, i.e $f(x)=C/x$. But then your integral diverges unless $C=0$, and in any case there were no assumptions given on $f$. For instance, say I pick the function $f(x)=x-2$ and values $\alpha,\beta=1$. Then $\int_0^4 f(t)dt=\color{Red}{0}$ but $2[\alpha f(\alpha)+\beta f(\beta)]=\color{Red}{-4}$. The claim is very very wrong; you must be communicating it incorrectly to us.

Comment: I believe the problem description is incomplete. One version could be prove that there exist $\alpha, \beta $ with $0 < \alpha, \beta < 2$ such that $\int_{0}^{4}f(t)\,dt = 2\{\alpha f(\alpha) + \beta f(\beta)\}$ with some conditions on $f$.

Comment: I will edit the question.